# WinRT Class Library : use ResourceDictionary only at design time

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

I'm currently developping a Windows Class Library for Windows 8.1 using MVVM design pattern. 
My library is called at runtime by an app. Xaml pages and component are included as embedded resources and readed at runtime with XamlReader. 
I use a custom resource dictionary. At runtime, it gives :

```
 var xamlStream = typeof(MyPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ResourceDictionnary.xaml");
        var sr = new StreamReader(xamlStream);
        var xamlPage = sr.ReadToEnd();
        ResourceDictionary dic = XamlReader.Load(xamlPage) as ResourceDictionary;
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
```

This works at runtime but not for design in VS. 
Is there a way to specify to VS to use a resource dictionary only for design mode ?

Thanks by advance